# Xcode 5 not editing

Tags: ios, xcode5

Im using Xcode 5,
I sent my app to apple for approval this week, it passed validation. Now when I open the apps storyboard and I get on adding more stuff for the next version, I click run and it does not show anything that I have changed or added, even the most simple thing, like adding a plain label on a view. It does not apply it and you cant see a change!! Is it something to do with adding new schemes or something?
What should I do?

Comment: This could be anything. Try the usual first: verify you're building the correct target and the code takes the correct execution path. If it does: clean build, delete app from device & simulator, reboot computer & devices, try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step when weird stuff like this happens: Quit Xcode and do a manual cleaning of everything, as I explain in this answer: [How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)

There is another, more difficult-to-track-down issue, where Xcode will actually show you the wrong file. This can happen for example if you have two separate projects that are versions of the same project. You can open a storyboard and it will show you the storyboard from the other project, so your edits do happen but they go into the wrong file. This seems to happen especially if you're using the assistant editor (two panes at once). I'm sorry not to have more details, but it's so difficult to reproduce that I haven't even been able to report it as a bug to Apple, even though it has happened to me several times.